# What is analysis of deviance in linear mixed effect models?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, deviance

I am using lmer in R. My response variable is gene expression (15 genes altogether, just using one in the example) and my fixed effects are disease status and also age. My code is as follows;

```
  mod1<-lmer(gene1 ~ disgroup + age + (1|Family.ID), data=gene.data, REML=F, na.action=na.omit)
  mod2<- lmer(gene1 ~ age + (1|Family.ID), data=gene.data, REML=F, na.action=na.omit).

  compare<-anova(mod1, mod2)
```

I understand I am comparing the fit of the data when comparing mod1 and mod2, as disease status is missing from mod2 it will help me to determine whether disease status improves the fit of the data. In other words, would it be correct to say that the p value generated from this anova ( F test?) will help me to determine whether there is a relationship between this gene and the disease status? Null hypothesis being there is no relationship.

Secondly, the estimate/effect size for disease status in model 1 is very small = 6x10^-3. In context, how would you explain this? Would you say that there is little association between this gene and the disease status ( the Pr > t value is also less than 0.05).

Lastly, please explain what analysis of the deviance is ( in my context would this explain the deviance between the mod1 and mod2) and how is this calculated (via Pr>|Chisq|?).

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Edit: Models do contain a random effect which would be the Family ID ( one or two of the participants are relatives).

Comment: I don’t see a random effect, and I don’t see a link function. Are you sure this isn’t just a usual OLS problem? Find a copy of Agresti’s Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models, and read the section on likelihood ratio testing in the GLM chapter (around page 130).

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the reference. I have edited my post above, random effects are included ( one of which is Family ID as mentioned above), therefore I will need to use a linear mixed model not a generalized linear model.

Comment: The `anova()` function when applied in this way (to a set of models) performs a [likelihood ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test), not an F test. In other words, here you are comparing a _full_ model (in which the coefficient for disease status is a free parameter) with a _reduced_ one, in which the coefficient for disease status is set to zero.

Comment: The use of a $\chi^2$ (chi-squared) distribution comes from [Wilk's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks%27_theorem), which states that ratio of the maximized likelihoods of the two models (or more precisely, minus twice the log of that ratio) asymptotically approaches a chi-squared distribution. Thus, the p-value from this test does help you determining whether the disease status is useful to predict variation in gene expression.

Comment: @matteo Thank you very much for the above, my understanding is a lot clearer. With regards to the estimate/effect size of my disease status (just looking at mod1) which is 6.02e-3, and the p value is 0.42 (from a t-test), this is basically telling me that there is little association between this gene and the disease status? However, if for another gene it was significant and the effect size was large per se, I cannot tell which group, control or disease, the gene has a significant association with? I'm sorry if this is simple, I am new to mixed models.

Comment: @matteo I think my confusion now lies with the analysis of deviance meaning ( I have seen analysis of deviance tables with a Chisq value, df and then also the Pr>Chisq. Often including the term Type II Wald chi square tests) . I'll update my post if I find something that helps.